# iterate over a map instead of a list

Tags: java, list, hashmap, converters

My code for presenting results looks like this:

```
    private void presentResult(List<Long> result) {
    if(result.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No matching values for the provided query.");
    }       
    for(String s : result) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

But I want to return a hashmap instead of a list so I want it to be like this:

```
    private void presentResult(Map<LocalDate, Long> result) {
    if(result.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No matching values for the provided query.");
    }       
    for(Map<LocalDate, Long> s : result) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

But then I get this error: "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"
How can it be solved?

Comment: You are talking about a `parameter`, not the return value

Comment: You're asking how to **iterate** a map, not how to return it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map)

Comment: You are talking about the input parameter of the method, not the return type. Better is to follow some good tutorial and learn the language vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking how to iterate a map, instead of list. You can iterate the map like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `result.entrySet()`. That returns a `Set<Entry<LocalDate, Long>>>`, which is iterable (Map isn't).

Your loop would look like this:

```
for (Entry<LocalDate, Long> s : result.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(s.getKey() + " - " + s.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use entrySet of map.

```
for(Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long> s : result.entrySet) 
{ 
    System.out.println(s.getKey()); 
    System.out.println(s.getValue());
}
```